# Amazon Aurora Hierarchy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am new to Amazon Aurora database. I am clear that all the instances are under cluster volume. I can see multiple databases in a single instances. How does it allocate computing(Memory,IO and CPU) power to different databases. If I have 5 Databases and if I want to have different compute power to different Databases, How to config that.  Can I get some kind of hierarchy diagram for Amazon Aurora like Amazon cluster --> Cluster Volume --> Instances --> Databases like this.

Trying to understand the architecture of Amazon Aurora

Comment: You can't do that at all. Each instance will have the same data. All databases/schemas will be replicated to each cluster instance. There is no way to dedicate compute power to a particular database/schema. If you want to do that, you would have to create a separate cluster for each database.

Comment: @MarkB So It's just a logical grouping with database/schema name. Physically all these data stored in the same cluster volume. All the databases are sharing the compute power.

Comment: Each instance is like having Postgrees or MySQL installed on your local laptop, with multiple databases/schemas created inside that Postgres or MySQL installation. The databases/schemas are just a software construct inside the Postgres or MySQL software. There is no way to dedicate specific CPU cores or RAM to a specific database or schema.

Answer (score 1):

Each instance is like having Postgrees or MySQL installed on your local laptop, with multiple databases/schemas created inside that Postgres or MySQL installation. The databases/schemas are just a software construct inside the Postgres or MySQL software. There is no way to dedicate specific CPU cores or RAM to a specific database or schema.